# TCPDF: how to pass an image to header (not blurry)

Tags: pdf

Passing a logo-image into the header of a Pdf-Document via "tcpdf" needs millimeter as unit. I dont have millimeters. The image have pixels as width and height.
However, every value i tried out, it was blurry.

```
    /**
 * Set header data.
 * @param $ln (string) header image logo
 * @param $lw (string) header image logo width in mm
 * @param $ht (string) string to print as title on document header
 * @param $hs (string) string to print on document header
 * @param $tc (array) RGB array color for text.
 * @param $lc (array) RGB array color for line.
 * @public
 */
public function setHeaderData($ln='', $lw=0, $ht='', $hs='', $tc=array(0,0,0), $lc=array(0,0,0)) {
```

I have a logo both as an jpeg-image and as a png-image. Both images has extends as a width and a height-parameter messed in pixel.

However, TCPDF needs a value in Millimeter.

How can i determine the right parameter, so i can pass a jpeg or png image into the header of a TCPDF-created PDF-File?

I opened up these files in GIMP and tried out the scale-image-dialog. I could determine the width and height in millimeters, but passed to TCPDF, the image is still blurry...

Answer (score 1):

How are you viewing the 'blurry' image - in Adobe's PDF reader? If so, make sure you have the PDF size set at 100%. My Adobe reader opens docs @167%, so the image(s) used to create the PDF doc in TCPDF appear 'blurry' until I view the doc at 100%.